# What is the best way to make parameters public in a factory function?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, factory

I have the factory function/mixin pasted below working, but I can't access any of the parameters from outside.

I tried to return `xPosition`, `yPosition` like this, but it did not work.

```
    return Object.assign({},
    attacker(state),
    renderer(state),
    xPosition,
    yPosition
);
```

I would like to be able to move the zombie without having to write special methods contained in the object.

I would like to keep the factory as close as possible to how it is now.

The whole thing is in an ES6 module, so it's private to the rest of the code anyway.

THANKS!

```
var zombie = createZombie (100,100);

var renderer = function renderer(state) {
return {
    render() {
        ...
    }
  };
};

var createZombie = function createZombie(xPosition, yPosition) {

var state = {
    status: 1,
    width: 10,
    height: 10,
    xPosition,
    yPosition,
    angle: 0,
    color: "green"
};

return Object.assign({},
    attacker(state),
    renderer(state),
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.assign` expects objects as its arguments so just pass the positions as part of an object:

```
return Object.assign({},
    attacker(state),
    renderer(state),
    {
      xPosition,
      yPosition
    }
);
```

Comment: Good point, if that exact `state` object is meant to be persistent, your approach is the way to go

Comment: Jonas, I am afraid i don't understand what you are meaning by "numbers are passed by value, not by reference", could you explain what you mean in the context of my program?

Comment: @Sumomo, it means that after you add the `xPosition` and `yPosition` values to the returned object, any further changes to those values in the internal `state` won't be reflected in the returned object.

Comment: @sumomo if you do e.g. `state.xPosition++` somewhere on your code, the returned objects `xPosition` does not change as theyre not the same reference.

Comment: But i am only returning the object once when I initialize all my zombies into a big array. From then on I want to do things like zombie[1].xPosition++ to move them around. Is this a bad way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

```
return Object.assign({},
   attacker(state),
   renderer(state),
   {
     get xPosition(){ return state.xPosition;},
     set xPosition(v){ return state.xPosition = v;},      
     get yPosition(){ return state.yPosition;},      
     set yPosition(v){ return state.yPosition = v;}      
  }
);
```

However while using getters and setters is plausible, its a poor design pattern in my opinion. Maybe you could rather trust the people around you to follow the _ convention...

```
return Object.assign({},
  attacker(state),
  renderer(state),
  { _state: state }
);
```